# Trying to run libGDX with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, libgdx, dependencies, lwjgl

Maybe a newbie question...

I've been working on a LWJGL project, where I use Maven to manage dependencies. In it, I want to use some parts of the libgdx library. So I figured I will first run at least a helloworld working with it before I add it to my main project.

So in my pom.xml I have this:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-backend-lwjgl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx-backend-lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

The other contents of the file are the same as in a working project and are 100% working.

I tried creating a separate libgdx project before that and... it didn't work. But, I saw that the code that was supposed to run the program was:

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new SomeApplicationListenerFile(), config);
    }
```

So I used that in my maven project.
When I do "run as a Java Application", the error is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration
    at org.boby.RayTracing.main.Main.main(Main.java:179)
```

And if I do a Maven Build, it tells me that "package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist"

I looked for that package in the jars Maven downloaded in the "Maven dependencies" folder and I found it in gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.11.jar - right where it should be.

The package is apparently there, but Java cannot find it. How can I fix that?

Some additional information:
Windows 10, eclipse oxygen, Maven 3.6.0, JRE 1.8.0_191, JDK 8

Thank you in advance! I've been banging my head on this for hours.

Edit: I made some progress. Looks like the "test" was messing things up so I removed those statements. Now I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx64.dll' for target: Windows 10, 64-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:125)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:33)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNativesLoader.load(LwjglNativesLoader.java:47)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:83)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:71)
    at org.boby.RayTracing.main.Main.main(Main.java:178)
```

It looks like I need to include gdx-natives.jar in my dependencies, but I can't find a maven repository for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can let Maven do the work if you define the gdx-platform dep like this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
            <classifier>natives-desktop</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This will load the natives jar including the gdx64.dll so you don't have to add any external jar to your project in the build path.

A side note is: if you use the standard Maven repo directory structure and you load assets with the Gdx.files.internal("fileName") statement you need to define a folder in the main/repository with the same name as the package you have your code in. (i.e. main/java/myPackage relates to /main/repository/myPackage). I struggled a bit with this because I don't normaly have to define a package folder int the repository dir.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded gdx-natives.jar (saw it in a forum thread). In there, was a file named "gdx-64.dll". As I need "gdx64.dll", I just renamed the dll and now it runs.