# Downloading libGDX setup

Tags: java, libgdx

I've recently come across libGDX for java game development and wanted to give it a try. Every tutorial i've looked up showed that i have to download the setup.jar from https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com. The problem i'm having is that upon visiting this site, i always get redirected to https://libgdx.com, where all i can find are features, a doc, news... and a git repo with code.

Can someone explain to me how i can still download the setup app. Or do i have to run the code from git? Maybe this is a completely stupid question and i'm missing something really obvious but currently i'm completely lost.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289080/trying-to-run-libgdx-with-maven-and-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Website of the libGdx Developers has changed.

I researched a bit and found out that they provide you useful tools for programming with libgdx.
The tool list contains the Setup Tool.
You can find a list of the tools here:

https://libgdx.com/dev/tools/

However I have had ungreat experiences with the tool.
If the tool installation does not work properly. I would recommend you to try to install it manually.
You can find informations about the Manual installation here:

https://libgdx.com/dev/project-generation/

Comment: Thank you very much...this was exactly what i was looking for!